# How to merge row values in same column depending on values of another column row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can any help on solve this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6qoU.png)

In this scenario, if the column 1 and column 2 row is None then we need to merge and the column 0 should not be None, the we we need merge the row with above row

in this case row 0 **0  amoxicillin (trihydrate) cap 250 mg     1        4** this ok w e don't need todo anything to this

but if we see row 5 **125 mg/5ml                                None    None** in this case col 0 is having some value but col1 and col2 is None, so we need to merge col 0 row value with previous row value which is 4 row and if the all are None the should remove those base on condition only

Comment: what about row 7?

Answer (score 0):

let say your original data frame is `df` which contains data as this:

```py
                                      0     1     2
0   amoxicillin (trihydrate) cap 250 mg     1     4
1                                  None  None  None
2   amoxicillin (trihydrate) cap 500 mg     1     t
3     amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp     1     h
4                                  None  None  None
5                           125 mg/5ml   None  None
6                                  None  None  None
7     amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp  None  None
8                            200 mg/5ml  None  None
9                                  None  None  None
10    amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp     1  None
11                                 None  None  None
12                           250 mg/5ml  None  None
13    amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp     1  None
14                           400 mg/5ml  None  None
15  amoxicillin (trihydrate) tab 500 mg     1  None
16  amoxicillin (trihydrate) tab 875 mg     1  None
```

Now we will replace `None` with `NaN` and drop row which are all `Nan` by:

```py
df = df.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna(how='all')
mask = df.isnull()
final = pd.DataFrame()
i,j = 0,0
for index,row in mask.iterrows():
    if row[1] and row[2]:
        final.iloc[j-1,0] = final.iloc[j-1,0] + " " + df.iloc[i,0]
    else:
        final = final.append(df.iloc[i])
        j+=1
    i+=1
print(final)
```

we create one more data frame as `mask` which contains bool value base on null or not and iterate over every row of data frame to check condition and append result to `final` data frame:

```py
#result
                                                    0  1    2
0                 amoxicillin (trihydrate) cap 250 mg  1    4
2                 amoxicillin (trihydrate) cap 500 mg  1    t
3   amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp 125 mg/5ml  ...  1    h
10       amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp 250 mg/5ml  1  NaN
13       amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp 400 mg/5ml  1  NaN
15                amoxicillin (trihydrate) tab 500 mg  1  NaN
16                amoxicillin (trihydrate) tab 875 mg  1  NaN
```

Comment: In your given data row 7 does not contain any value in col 1 and col 2, hence it will merge with above row

Comment: but when i execute this code i'm getting  output like                                                   0    1     2
0                 amoxicillin (trihydrate) cap 250 mg  1.0   4.0
1                 amoxicillin (trihydrate) cap 500 mg  1.0     t
2        amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp 125 mg/5ml  1.0     h
4        amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp 200 mg/5ml  1.0     2
6        amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp 250 mg/5ml  1.0  None
8        amoxicillin (trihydrate) for susp 400 mg/5ml  1.0  None

Comment: So does you get your aspected results or not ?